# Cannot run my code in SWI prolog (Windows)

Tags: compiler-errors, prolog

A have been trying to learn some prolog code, but it seems I failed really fast, as I cannot run the code I create.

The code might be simple as:

```
loves(romeo,juliet). 

loves(juliet,romeo) :- loves(romeo,juliet).
```

And i call it prolog.pl, but if i input consult('prolog.pl')., or using reconsult, or [prolog]., I always get this:

```
ERROR: Type error: `dict' expected, found `prolog' (an atom)
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] throw(error(type_error(dict,prolog),_10810))
ERROR:    [9] '$dicts':'.'(prolog,pl,_10850) at c:/program files/swipl/boot/dicts.pl:46
ERROR:    [8] '<meta-call>'(user:(...,...)) <foreign>
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

I've also tried to specify the path, but nothing seems to work here. So please, just help me out!

Comment: Are you sure you entered `consult('prolog.pl')` and not `consult(prolog.pl)`? You would see that error if you entered the latter.

Comment: @That_Guy It's raised  `existence_error` (or directory) on my machine. Which version of SWI-Prolog do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I'm 2 years late...

According to the error message, SWI prolog is having a problem while reading a startup file called dicts.pl containing basic prolog primitives. It hasn't begun to read your file.

The best thing to do is un-install, download a fresh installation and re-install.

Comment: Hahah
Thanks for the help, friend